# Adding reference to Windows Phone Toolkit in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reference, windows-phone-7.1

I'm busy with a windows phone app and need to use a expandable list control. After some searching I found that one can just download and add a reference to the Windows Phone Toolkit.

The instructions on what .dll file to use and add to your project seem to be a bit out dated. Or at least the instructions I'm finding. Apparently you have to add the dll file to you project located here:

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.1\Toolkit\Aug11\Bin\Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit.dll

But the directories in my PC is not the same. I can follow up to here:

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.1\

Then there's no 'Toolkit' folder, etc. I just wanted to find out if someone can point out where to find this .dll that I have to reference on my project?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you can download the latest toolkit and get more information on it from here http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/94435. I hope it helps